# Merging specific rows in R

Tags: r, merge, plyr

I would like to merge the column values for only certain rows of my df. For example in the following df,

```
  name time value
1   n1    1    10
2   n2    2    12
3    a    3     6
4    b    3    NA
5   n3    4     4
```

I would like to combine rows 3 & 4 so that the final df will be,

```
  name time value
1   n1    1    10
2   n2    2    12
3    a    3     6
5   n3    4     4
```

#### My Method

After trying out different approaches I settled on,

```
df1 <- ddply(df,
             .(time), #Split by time as events "a","b" will always same time
             function(y){
               if(all(y$name %in% c("a","b"))){ #Dont combine rows without "a"|"b"
                 y<-data.frame(t(apply(y, 2, min, na.rm=T))) #adply doesn't seem to work?
                 print(y) #Added here for debugging
                 }  
               y
               }
             )
```

The print statement produces the correct answer,

```
  name time value
1    a    3     6
```

but the output df1 is

```
  name time value
1   n1    1    10
2   n2    2    12
3    a    1     1
4   n3    4     4
```

I have no idea how the 1's came??

Comment: You don't have a return value in your anonymous function.  Add a return value immediately after `print(y)`

Comment: the `y` after the `if{}` block is the return statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is type conversions. In your `apply` call, the `data.frame` is converted to a `matrix` of type `character`. When you convert it to a `data.frame`, the `character`s are converted to `factor`. And then when combining the results, the `factor` is converted to `numeric`. To avoid the conversion to factors, you can use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and your code will work.

```
df1 <- ddply(df,
             .(time), #Split by time as events "a","b" will always same time
             function(y){
               if(all(y$name %in% c("a","b"))){ #Dont combine rows without "a"|"b"
                 y<-data.frame(t(apply(y, 2, min, na.rm=T)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
               }  
               y
             }
)
```

Anyway, here's an alternative solution, which is a bit easier to read, less error prone and probably faster.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[name %in% c("a","b"), `:=`(name=name[1], value=min(value, na.rm=TRUE)), by=time]
unique(dt)
```

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for your quick reply.
Do you also know why `adply(y, 2, min, na.rm=T)` throws an error `Error: only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Comment: Also,
Your second approach is better but my actual data frame contains 18 columns and I don't want to add a min statement for each of it.
Is there a better approach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why couldn't you use `duplicated` to remove the repeated `time` values (rows)?

```
> dat
#   name time value
# 1   n1    1    10
# 2   n2    2    12
# 3    a    3     6
# 4    b    3    NA
# 5   n3    4     4
> dat[!duplicated(dat$time), ]
#   name time value
# 1   n1    1    10
# 2   n2    2    12
# 3    a    3     6
# 5   n3    4     4
```

Comment: Oh.. this was just an example scenario, my actual case consists of multiple value columns and I need to take the min value for consecutive rows with names "a" | "b"